# Congratulations on another strong Winter Bash for Matter Modelers in 2022!

Tags: discussion, participation, winter-bash, congratulations

#### As Winter Bash 2022 comes to an end I want to thank everyone who participated!

This is a follow-up to last year's post: [Congratulations! Matter Modeling rocked at Winter Bash 2021!](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/315/5) I was initially a lot less enthusiastic about Winter Bash this year compared to last year, but [Geoff Hutchison](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/users/30/geoff-hutchison)'s huge number of hats early into the festivities, inspired me to pick up the pace and get more involved.

Far more hats were available this year, and things were a bit strange, in that users from other parts of the network could get at least 16 hats on MMSE without even posting anything on MMSE, so that explains why PeterJ is #2 below, but I'm especially happy to see so many **new users** on our Winter Bash leaderboard:

[image]

The 2022 Winter Bash was even more difficult than last year to collect hats on MMSE (we again had the hat from last year which was impossible to earn on MMSE due to requiring 5 reopen reviews on a site that didn't even require that many reviews, but now there were equally impossible hats for reviewing things like low-quality posts and suggested edits; plus there was a hat which required 100 upvotes, which has never even happened once on MMSE), and this was combined with the awarding of "passive" hats which gave an advantage to bigger sites like Artificial Intelligence SE for hat totals (e.g. notice PeterJ's avatar in the top user list for *every single* site in the image below!). Despite those disadvantages, ***we still*** ranked better than a lot of bigger and older sites, and close to the middle among the total 180 SE sites in the network:

[image]

Overall, I was so happy to see so many matter modelers keeping this site warm during the holiday season.

#### Thanks again everyone, see you next year!

Comment: "*[hat's off](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/575743/217285)!*"